# How to input the value of the input group of checkbox in the controller parameter ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I have some trouble about making input a group of checkboxes on `Devextreme` cell template form, but when I try to submit all input value has passed to parameter controller except checkboxes value. Can anyone help how to solve it?

This is my devextreme code:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<ERP.Models.ViewModels.UserDataVM>()
            .ID("gridContainer")
            .DataSource(d => d.Mvc()
            .Controller("UserDatas")
            .LoadAction("UserDataHeader")
            .InsertAction("InsertUserData")
            .UpdateAction("UpdateUserData")
            .DeleteAction("DeleteUserData")
            .Key("UserDataID"))
            .AllowColumnResizing(true)
            .RemoteOperations(true)
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.AddFor(m => m.UserDataID).Visible(false).SortOrder(SortOrder.Desc).FormItem(x => x.Visible(false));
                columns.AddFor(m => m.AspNetUserID).Visible(false).SortOrder(SortOrder.Desc).FormItem(x => x.Visible(false));
                columns.AddFor(m => m.DeviceID).Visible(false).FormItem(x => x.Visible(false));
                columns.AddFor(m => m.Name);
                columns.AddFor(m => m.Email);
                columns.AddFor(m => m.Status).Lookup(lookup => lookup
                .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("UserDatas").LoadAction("StatusLookup").Key("Value"))
                .DisplayExpr("Text")
                .ValueExpr("Value"));
                columns.AddFor(m=>m.Perusahaan).Caption("Perusahaan").Name("Perusahaan").EditCellTemplate(
                    @<text>
                        <div class="option-list" style="display: flex; flex-flow: row;width: max-content;">
                            <div class="option-item" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;margin-right:20px">
                                @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox().Text("Company 100"))
                                @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox().Text("Company 2"))
                                @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox().Text("Company 3"))
                            </div>
                            <div class="option-item" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;margin-right:20px">
                                @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox().Text("Perusahaan 4"))
                                @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox().Text("Perusahaan 5"))
                                @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox().Text("Perusahaan 6"))
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </text>
                ).Visible(false);
            })
            .ShowBorders(true)
            .Editing(editing =>
            {
                //editing.Mode(GridEditMode.Cell);
                editing.Mode(GridEditMode.Form);
                editing.AllowUpdating(new JS("checkAccess('User','Update')"));
                editing.AllowAdding(new JS("checkAccess('User','Insert')"));
                editing.AllowDeleting(new JS("checkAccess('User','Delete')"));
            })
            .Grouping(g => g.AutoExpandAll(false))
            .OnInitNewRow("function(e) { e.data.UserDataID = 0; }")

            .MasterDetail(md => md
            .Enabled(true)
            .Template(new TemplateName("gridContainer-details")))
        )
```